# uninstalled ca-certificates

Tags: linux, arch-linux, pacman

I uninstalled ca-certificates without realizing the consequences that would have. Now I can't reinstall it. Even a manual install by downloading the ca-certificates package with firefox and installing it with  `sudo pacman -U ca-certificates*` didn't work. How can it be reinstalled?

Comment: `installing it with sudo pacman -U ca-certificates* didn't work` - maybe you could show the output?

Comment: it looks for mirrors but errors out each time with the message: 
error setting certificate verify locations:  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CApath: none

Comment: the file does acctually exist, but it's an empty file

Comment: I think you may have to download the source file manually then extract the files into /etc/ssl/certs. After that, you need to run the update to regenerate `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt `. On opensuse, it's `/usr/sbin/update-ca-certificates`, but on arch, I assume it will be something else.

Answer (score 2):

I had to use a live USB of Arch Linux.

There I ran the command

```
pacstrap -Mi ca-certificates
```

After rebooting on the actual system I had to run

```
sudo update-ca-certificates
sudo update-ca-trust
sudo rm /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
ln -s /etc/ca-certificates/extracted/ca-bundle.trust.crt /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Now it works again

`ca-certificates` is a package that is essential for pacman as I had to find out and thus should treated as a dependency of pacman.